# Windows: Avoid or Disable Backups on Files

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8, cloud, backup

[Protecting user files with File History](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/07/10/protecting-user-files-with-file-history.aspx) talks about File History, which is basically a continuous backup for Windows 8. The blog discusses File History in depth, and also discusses how to integrate SkyDrive.

I want to programmatically disable backup of certain files. The files live on another server, and there's no need to back them up locally or put them on someone else's cloud. The blog and related articles doe not talk about opt'ing out of the service for application data.

How does one programmatically: (1) disable local file backups; and (2) disable cloud based backups. I'm interested in settings for both Windows 8 (desktop or laptop) and Windows Phone 8.

Related: Both Android and Apple have similar. For Android, we add `android:allowBackup` and set it to `false` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. For Apple, we can use `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` file property or `com.apple.MobileBackup` extended attribute.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8, backup and restore settings are controlled by the user through system settings. An app cannot prevent itself from being backed up. However, note that the backup does **not** store any data associated with third party apps but rather only stores a list of installed apps

So basically you don't need to do anything in your app to prevent local files from being stored on SkyDrive if the user has enabled backup.

In Windows 8 everything can be backed up since an admin user will have full access to his computer files, I don't think you can restrict this. If you have sensitive data you can use [`DataProtectionProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx) to protect it.

Comment: Thanks Alaa. Window's backup looks very immature at the moment. Apple progressed down the same path a long time ago. Note the progression at [How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).

Comment: Yea, backup has only been introduced in Windows Phone 8. Windows RT is still relatively new so it will probably be a while till it provides these features which might be considered minor by the OS developers.

Comment: One last question Alaa. [Protecting user files with File History](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/07/10/protecting-user-files-with-file-history.aspx) appears to provide continuous backup. Is there a way to opt-out programmaticly? (I'm going to update my question with the info for others).

Comment: I am not 100% sure, I have never came across an api or settings that lets you opt out of backups so I would have to say likely no.